# doPost not working in Google app script

Tags: post, google-apps-script

I came across various questions but none of them could solve my problem. I wrote a simple `doPost()` code in google app script:

```
function doPost(e){
  Logger.log("Hello World");
}
```

Then I deployed it as a web app and pasted the url on hurl.it to make a post request. However, there is nothing being logged in the log and the response is 200 (Ok). I think it is not going inside this `doPost()` function.  Can anyone guide as to what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 17):

Your implementation does not meet all the requirements needed for a web app. Here's an excerpt from the documentation ([link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#requirements_for_web_apps)):

> **Requirements for web apps**
>
> A script can be published as a web app if it meets these requirements:
>
> - It contains a `doGet(e)` or `doPost(e)` function.
> - The function returns an HTML service `HtmlOutput` object or a content service `TextOutput` object.

Here are some examples:

```
function doGet(e) {
  var params = JSON.stringify(e);
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(params);
}

function doPost(e) {
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(e.parameter));
}
```

And just for completeness, you must also redeploy your web App as a new version every time you make changes to the code. Redeploying under an already existing version does not work, you have to make a new version for your changes to take hold.

Also using the standard `Logger.log` to trace changes within `doGet(e)` or `doPost(e)` is unreliable with web apps as they are executed asynchronously. I would recommend logging your output to a spreadsheet. There is an awesome script library called BetterLog that extends the Logger API to do just that; it can be found at the following link:

https://github.com/peterherrmann/BetterLog

---

**UPDATE 2018-07-18**

Apps Script now supports StackDriver Logging which is accessible from the Apps Scripts editor's View menu.

Answer (score 9):

in order for the "exec" version of the published Web App URL to run with any new changes, you must publish a new version **every time** that you make a change to your script.  It does not matter how small the change is.  Instead of using `Logger.log("Hello World");` I would write a value to a spreadsheet.

```
SpreadsheetApp.openById(id).getSheetByName(name).appendRow(['test']);
```

There are 2 different URL's for your Web App.  One with 'dev' on the end and the other with 'exec' on the end.  The 'dev' version is always the current code.  The 'exec' version never changes unless you publish a new version.

Comment: had a hard time to figure out why my script not working - finally it is start working only after i made new deployment

Answer (score 2):

I struggled with this for AWHILE NOW and I finally got lucky.
I use w3schools alot so I read fully on the form element and its attributes. 
The ACTION attribute seems to be the key in getting doPost(e) to work for me and GAS.

1. Here's my HTML (removed opening and closing angle brackets)

```
<form 
action="https://script.google.com/a/[org]/macros/s/[scriptID]/exec" 
method="post" target="_blank" >

        First name: input type="text" name="fname"<br>
        Last name: input type="text" name="lname"<br>
input type="submit" value="Submit"
</form>
```

2. Here's my doPost ( the Logger ran as well as the new window displaying e.parameter)

```
function doPost(e){
  Logger.log("I WAS RAN!!")
  if(typeof e !== 'undefined') {
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(e.parameter));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the reason can be you are using a Rest client like Postman. It won't work, though I don't know the reason why.

Try with a normal form like this and it will work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfyc.../exec">
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="param1" value="ABC">
  <br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="param2" value="XYZ">
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 

</body>
</html>
```