# How to add headers to doPost() in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, cors

I am trying to configure Google Apps Script to call a function `myFunction()` whenever a client sends an HTTP POST request to the published URL (https://script.google.com/XXXXXXX/exec)

But I get the CORS error when I try it.

> Failed to load https://script.google.com/XXXXXXX/exec: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8081' is therefore not allowed access.

Is there any way to add CORS headers to my server `doPost()` response?

Code.gs

```
function doPost(e){
  // this is where I feel I should add something like:
  // var options = { headers: {"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"} }
  myFunction(e);
}

function myFunction(e){
  // do stuff
}
```

Comment: The error message sounds like you set permission incorrectly on your Google Script. It needs to be published as allow access for anyone, even anonymous.

Comment: Your doPost() is not implemented properly. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45163563/dopost-not-working-in-google-app-script/45165643#45165643.