# doPost appScript with webhook, Post request received but is not Running doPost

Tags: webhooks, trello

I am setting up a appScript to run on a webhook that has been registered to a Trello api. I want the doPost function in to run every time the specific trello board performs a post.

Steps I have done to setup

1. Published as web app, selected "Anyone" as who is able to run
2. Used the code below to register the webhook with the proper keys, this successfully creates a webhook for trello

```
fetch('https://api.trello.com/1/webhooks/?key=XXX&token=XXX&callbackURL=https://script.google.com/macros/s/XXX/exec&idModel=XXX&description=Description', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json'
  }
})
  .then(response => {
    console.log(
      `Response: ${response.status} ${response.statusText}`
    );
    return response.text();
  })
  .then(text => console.log(text))
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

3. Republished web app, selected "Anyone, even anonymous" to be able to run

Other Notes:

I have created a doPost function and a doGet function, both have logging in them

I am using the "exec" callback URL in the webhook, this seemed to be the only thing that would be able to trigger the doPost function

When a post is performed by the trello api, the doPost function is properly triggered, but even with the logging present in the doPost, I am not able to see any results that the doPost function has actually been run. See
[doPostCompletion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CeEoL.png)

Am I missing something that needs to be deployed or adjusted?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out Logger.log is properly respected in a synchronous manner with doPost.
Webhook was functional all along.

Sources:
[doPost not working in Google app script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45163563/dopost-not-working-in-google-app-script)

https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script#corsinwebapps